# Cannot store to object array because "this.share" is null

Tags: java, arrays, oop, object

I have to create an object array, but I can't figure out why it is instantiating to null every time. The class' constructor is not empty, it has 2 parameters, so I can't initialize it with `new Share()`.

```
public class Portfolio {

    private Share[] share;
    private int noShares = 0;

    public Portfolio() {}                                               //constructor

    public void addShare(Share s) {

        share[noShares++] = new Share(s.getValue(), s.getCompany());

    }
```

I have also tried this, but it gives the same error

```
share[noShares].setValue(s.getValue));
share[noShares++].setCompany(s.getCompany);
```

And this is the last method

```
    public double computeSum() {

        int sum = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < noShares; i++) {

            sum += share[noShares].getValue();

        }

        return sum;

    }

}
```

Comment: error at com.company.Portfolio.addShare(Portfolio.java:12)

Comment: so, instantiate share.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html have a look at "allocates memory for 10 integers"

Comment: You need to do something like ``public Share[] shares = new Share[n];`` where n is the number of elements you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign the size of the Array, before you create an Object that you want to insert. Right now you are declaring an Array, without a size, and you are trying to add one Share Object to the entire array.

```
public class Portfolio {
    
    //Declare and initialize the Array
    private Share[] share = new Share[Amount of share objects that you want to save];

    //Now you can add the actual objects in the Array
    Share[index] = new Share(int x, int y....);

}
```

I hope that i was able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public class Portfolio {

    private Share[] share = new Share[100]; //or whatever number of elements

}
```

You need to intantiate/assign memory to the array beforehand.

Comment: Still doesn't work